# Gitlab CICD Scan and Upload SonarQube Reports to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have configured pipeline for maven project which is using SonarQube instance to scan code and publish reports over to SonarQube instance dashboard.

**I am trying to implement solution in which I don't need SonarQube Server, I only need SonarQube docker container to scan the code and generate reports instead of publishing reports and show in SonarQube dashboard, it should only send those reports to s3 bucket. i.e. only need report files**

I have knowledge about all the pieces like pushing artifacts to s3 and SonarQube container scanning, but only problem is I am unable to find a solution for my scenario.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think you have everything u need. You just need to use the docker image and add a job and check if it works.

Comment: @Origin actually i am concerned about "reports files" location which SonarQube uses to showcase on dashboard, so after finding location then i will be able upload those files as artifacts.


also second thing is we are talking about inside container so if i find location then is there any easy way that from inside sonarqube container i will upload files to s3.